# How can I echo the position number of SQL row in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Before you misread the title... I'm ***not*** asking how to echo the number of rows, I'm simply looking to find the position that the row is in.

Let's say we have `five` total rows:

```
+---------------------+
| Post ID | Author |
+---------------------+
|    463 | Me     |
|    477 | Me     |
|    718 | Me     |
|    883 | Me     |
|    276 | Me     |
+---------------------+
```

Now I'd like to get the position of the row that contains the post ID of `718`. From looking at the data, we can visually see that it is the third row in the data. How can I echo this in PHP?

Comment: Rows in an RDBMS table represent unordered sets, so position is meaningless in this context.

Comment: So, it's not possible then? @Strawberry

Comment: All things are possible. Some things are meaningless.

Comment: Whenever you do SQL query you know the exact position of the each row. How? you iterate through it so you know which one is first, second, and so on. Simply add a counter when you echo it. You might ask yourself how do i know the row number if i use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`? Well limit tells you how many you load and offset tells you how many you skipped. So the first row you get from an SQL query where you used `OFFSET` is `1 + <offset value>`.

Comment: you could try using ROW_NUMBER()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you fetch records, you may use a variable as position number.

```
#DB is a class connect to mysql database.
DB::init();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM RowNo ";
$stmt = DB::query( $sql );

$i = 1;
while( $rec1 = $stmt->fetch() ) {
    echo "row $i : ";
    print_r( $rec1 );
    echo '<BR>'.PHP_EOL;
    $i++;
};
```

result :

```
row 1 : Array ( [Post ID] => 8788277463 [Author] => Me )
row 2 : Array ( [Post ID] => 2894728477 [Author] => Me )
row 3 : Array ( [Post ID] => 3898994718 [Author] => Me )
row 4 : Array ( [Post ID] => 4891784883 [Author] => Me )
row 5 : Array ( [Post ID] => 1185819276 [Author] => Me )
```

Comment: If I add a `where` statement, would that still echo for the total number of rows or would it only echo for the new selection?

Comment: if you add a "where statement", result rows may changed. the loop will only show filtered records.

Answer (score 0):

You may use row_number :

#1. ORDER BY `Post ID`

SELECT * , row_number() over ( order by `Post ID` ) FROM `RowNo` order by `Post ID` asc

```
Post ID Author  row_number() over ( order by `Post ID` )    
1185819276  Me  1
2894728477  Me  2
3898994718  Me  3
4891784883  Me  4
8788277463  Me  5
```

#2. ORDER BY `Post ID` DESC

SELECT * , row_number() over ( order by `Post ID` desc ) FROM `RowNo` order by `Post ID` desc

```
Post ID Ascending 1 Author  row_number() over ( order by `Post ID` desc )   
8788277463  Me  1
4891784883  Me  2
3898994718  Me  3
2894728477  Me  4
1185819276  Me  5
```

#3. ORDER BY part of `Post ID`

SELECT * , substr(`Post ID`, 4, 2), row_number() over ( order by substr(`Post ID`, 4, 2) ) FROM `RowNo` order by substr(`Post ID`, 4, 2) asc

```
Post ID Author  substr(`Post ID`, 4, 2) Ascending 1 row_number() over ( order by substr(`Post ID`, 4, 2) )  
4891784883  Me  17  1
2894728477  Me  47  2
1185819276  Me  58  3
8788277463  Me  82  4
3898994718  Me  89  5
```

Comment: This is an answer to a different question